# tensor transformation in tensorflow 0.12

Tags: tensorflow

I have hacked into the bidirectional dynamic rnn. The output at each timestep and batchmember is a vector with 168 floats, of which 119 are for a character prediction task and the remaining 49 are for a classification task.

The static case converges nicely, but with the dynamic case I run into shape inference issues (tensorflow 0.12).

```
  outputs = rnn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(somestuff, time_major=False, scope="BiLSTM")
```

`outputs` has shape (32, ?, 168) where

```
- 32  is the batchsize,
- ?   is a placeholder getting fed the max-sequence-length inside the respective batch and
- 168 is my stepwise outputs-size (see above).
```

I need to process this in order to get two tensors:

```
1) with shape (32, ?, 119)
2) with shape (32, ?, 49)
```

Cant get my head around this. Or let's put it this way: The method I came up with for the static case involves an unstack-transformation. The unstack-method doesn't like a placeholder as a parameter. Any idea how to get from (32, ?, 168) to (32, ?, 119) and (32, ?, 49) in tensorflow 0.12?

Comment: Try this `tf.split(outputs, [119, 49], axis=2)`.

Comment: Is this feasable in r0.12?

Comment: In r0.12, there is a `tf.split_v` : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#split .

Comment: Yes, but the uneven split is what surprised me. I do use split, but I had to split into 168 tensors and then reput them together later. In r0.12 the specs say "Splits value along dimension split_dim into num_split smaller tensors. Requires that num_split evenly divide value.shape[split_dim]." So your "[119, 49]" surprised me. 
I circumvented my problem now by going time_major=True in the rnn, so my issue is solved, but I think your proposal is good only for version 1.0 and above.